# error in running npm install getting error for crypto and path module

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

i  tried the following command npm install to install all modules in my package.json file , get the following error

```
npm WARN package.json crypto@0.0.3 crypto is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json path@0.11.14 path is also the name of a node core module.
```

package.json has the entries for crypto@0.0.3 and path@0.11.14

Comment: the `crypto` module was not changed in five years - https://github.com/Gozala/crypto ;

Comment: isnt it core node modules? You dont need install them